# how to resolve "Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0

Tags: java, gradle, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

```
Could not resolve: org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server:5.5.2

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
```

which dependency version should i use?